# Google api version v1 vs v2

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play

I'm about to put my Android app, which uses google api v1 onto the market.  I now see that v1 has been depreciated and that I am urged to use v2 instead.  I see that v2 appears an order of magnitude more complex and that google play services are needed.

Since google play services are needed does that mean that my app will only be able to be distributed on google play and not, say, be distributed from my own web site?

thanks, Gary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Since google play services are needed does that mean that my app will
>   only be able to be distributed on google play

No, you can still distribute through any channel you want. It is a requirement for the device, not the distribution. The device your app installs on needs to have Google Play Services installed, which a number do.  It is very similar to the v1 maps which required the phones have Google Maps installed, reflected in the manifest via

```
<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps">
```

Answer (score 1):

Google likes to keep everybody using their own system as per usual. But it should still be possible to distribute via your website. You would need to save it as a .apk file.

[Heres](https://superuser.com/questions/499513/eclipse-save-as-apk-in-my-computer) how to save as .apk file

and [Heres](http://news.softpedia.com/news/How-to-Manually-Install-APK-Files-on-Android-Smartphones-150487.shtml) a tutorial on how users can download and install.